# RSS icon overlaps url in subscribe window

Tags: feature-request, design, feed

For example, on [locked-questions](/questions/tagged/locked-questions) page.

> [image]

It's ok to overlap, but 'cause icon has alpha background, it looks bad. Possible solutions:

1. Add padding.
2. Make white icon background.